# Simple integration that depends on floating point equality

Tags: c, math, floating-point, decimal

I have the following very-crude integration calculator:

```
// definite integrate on one variable
// using basic trapezoid approach
float integrate(float start, float end, float step, float (*func)(float x))
{
    if (start >= (end-step))
        return 0;
    else {
        float x = start; // make it a bit more math-like
        float segment = step * (func(x) + func(x+step))/2;
        return segment + integrate(x+step, end, step, func);
    }
}
```

And an example usage:

```
static float square(float x) {return x*x;}
int main(void)
{
    // Integral x^2 from 0->2 should be ~ 2.6
    float start=0.0, end=2.0, step=0.01;
    float answer = integrate(start, end, step, square);
    printf("The integral from %.2f to %.2f for X^2 = %.2f\n", start, end, answer );
}
```

```
$ run
The integral from 0.00 to 2.00 for X^2 = 2.67
```

What happens if the equality check at `start >= (end-step)` doesn't work? For example, if it evaluates something to 2.99997 instead of 3 and so does another loop (or one less loop). Is there a way to prevent that, or do most math-type calculators just work in decimals or some extension to the 'normal' floating points?

Comment: Let's start by asking why you're using recursion for something like this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist actually the whole point of this was to practice recursion. I'm just looking for some things I can write to help work on recursion, as it's something I struggle with.

Comment: If you want to practice recursion, then a better way to approach integration might be to divide the interval into two halves and call the routine recursively to integrate each half. The termination condition could be when the interval is smaller than some threshold or when a certain number of divisions has been performed. It is actually about the same amount of work for the computer but the call tree will have depth O(log n) instead of O(n), where n is the total number of subintervals.

Comment: @EricPostpischil that's a great idea, I think I'll try that one next!

Comment: Either way, you risk stack overflow. This is just not a good problem for recursion in general.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: Getting a stack overflow in the bisecting method would be a neat trick. It should use, what, 32 bytes of stack? Let’s splurge with 64 and say the OS gives us only a 1 MiB stack, of which 25% is used by overhead. So we have 3/4•2^20/64 call levels available. That’s 12,288 calls deep. We can’t bisect a normal `double` that many times because the IEEE-754 “double” format spans only 2098 powers of two.

Comment: @EricPostpischil. Correct. With bisection, your depth is log(n). Thinking about your suggested method, it's really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are given `step`, one way to write a loop (and you should use a loop for this, not recursion) is:

```
float x;
for (float i = 0; (x = start + i*step) < end - step/2; ++i)
    …
```

Some points about this:

- We keep an integer count with `i`. As long as there are a reasonable number of steps, there will be no floating-point rounding error in this. (We could make `i` and `int`, but `float` can count integer values perfectly well, and using `float` avoids an `int`-to-`float` conversion in `i*step`.)
- Instead of incrementing `x` (or `start` as it is passed by recursion) repeatedly, we recalculate it each time as `start + i*step`. This has only two possible rounding errors, in the multiplication and in the addition, so it avoids accumulating errors over repeated additions.
- We use `end - step/2` as the threshold. This allows us to catch the desired endpoint even if the calculated `x` drifts as far away from `end` as `end - step/2`. And that is about the best we can do, because if it is drifting farther than half a `step` away from the ideally spaced points, we cannot tell if it has drifted `+step/2` from `end-step` or `-step/2` from `end`.

This presumes that `step` is an integer division of `end-start`, or pretty close to it, so that there are a whole number of steps in the loop. If it is not, the loop should be redesigned a bit to stop one step earlier and then calculate a step of partial width at the end.

At the beginning, I mentioned being given `step`. An alternative is you might be given a number of steps to use, and then the step width would be calculated from that. In that case, we would use an integer number of steps to control the loop. The loop termination condition would not involve floating-point rounding at all. We could calculate `x` as `(float) i / NumberOfSteps * (end-start) + start`.

Comment: thanks for this great answer. Regarding `And that is about the best we can do...` -- are there any applications where that type of rounding is not acceptable and another approach needs to be used?\

Comment: @carl.hiass: If you have so many intervals or `end` and `start` are so close together that the rounding error exceeds half a step size, then some changes need to be made to avoid the rounding errors. That could be translating the endpoints (subtracting a fixed amount from them), especially if `f` can be modified to work with a translated argument, but it might involve other things depending on circumstances. It is likely more than is suitable to get into for a problem whose goal is simply to practice recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Two improvements can be made easily.

1. Using recursion is a bad idea. Each additional call creates a new stack frame. For a sufficiently large number of steps, you will trigger a Stack Overflow. Use a loop instead.
2. Normally, you would avoid the rounding problem by using `start`, `end` and `n`, the number of steps. The location of the `k`th interval would be at `start + k * (end - start) / n`;

So you could rewrite your function as

```
float integrate(float start, float end, int n, float (*func)(float x))
{
    float next = start;
    float sum = 0.0f;
    for(int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        float x = next;
        next = start + k * (end - start) / n; 
        sum += 0.5f * (next - x) * (func(x) + func(next));
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the stack overflow, yes it occurs for me when I decrease the step size pretty quickly.